# How are all the Eggsteroid levels opened?

Tags: angry-birds-space

I've gone through all the levels that come as part of the base game (Pig Bang, and Cold Cuts), and have only stumbled across one Eggsteroids level (#2, found on I believe Pig Bang, level 20 hiding in the bushes).

It appears there are currently 5 total Eggsteroids levels. Where can I find all the Eggsteroids and what is needed to unlock them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this guide for an answer:

http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/angry-birds-space-golden-eggsteroids-guide/

---

> **Eggsteroids #1 Pig Bang Level 1-9**
>
> Zoom out to see the Golden Eggsteroid hidden in the brush below the
>   two bubbled-pigs. Fire any of the Blue birds to reach it. This
>   Eggsteroid level pays homage to Space Invaders (1978).
>
> **Eggsteroids #2 Pig Bang Level 1-20**
>
> The Golden Eggsteroid is hidden in the tall brush atop the planet.
>   Fire a Lazer bird above it, then redirect him into the Eggsteroid.
>   This Eggsteroid level pays homage to Super Mario (1985).
>
> **Eggsteroids #3 Cold Cuts Level 2-13**
>
> Zoom out to see the Golden Eggsteroid in the brush on the planet below
>   the slingshot platform. Launch the Lazer bird backwards, then redirect
>   him into the Eggsteroid. This Eggsteroid level pays homage to Breakout
>   (1976).
>
> **Eggsteroids #4 Cold Cuts Level 2-25**
>
> Zoom out to see the Golden Eggsteroid on the underside of the
>   slingshot platform. Launch the Lazer bird downward to get a good
>   angle, then redirect him into the Eggsteroid. This Eggsteroid level
>   pays homage to Bubble Bobble (1986).
>
> **Eggsteroids #5 Cold Cuts Level 2-28**
>
> The Golden Eggsteroid is concealed under the snow pile, though the
>   concealing is sort of undone by the large flashing arrow pointing at
>   it. Launch any bird head-on into the snow pile to obtain the
>   Eggsteriod. This Eggsteroid level pays homage to Star Castle (1980).